# shared library constructor not working

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

In my shared library I have to do certain initialization at the load time. If I define the function with the GCC attribute `__attribute__ ((constructor))` it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't get called when the program linking my shared library is loaded.

If I change the function name to `_init()`, it works. Apparently the usage of `_init()` and `_fini()` functions are [not recommended](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP) now.

Any idea why `__attribute__ ((constructor))`  wouldn't work? This is with Linux 2.6.9, `gcc` version 3.4.6

**Edit:**

For example, let's say the library code is this the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int smlib_count;

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) setup(void) {
    smlib_count = 100;
    printf("smlib_count starting at %d\n", smlib_count);
}

void smlib_count_incr() {
    smlib_count++;
    smlib_count++;
}

int smlib_count_get() {
    return smlib_count;
}
```

For building the .so I do the following:

```
gcc -fPIC -c smlib.c
ld -shared -soname libsmlib.so.1 -o libsmlib.so.1.0 -lc smlib.o
ldconfig -v -n .
ln -sf libsmlib.so.1 libsmlib.so
```

Since the .so is not in one of the standard locations I update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and link the .so from a another program. The constructor doesn't get called. If I change it to `_init()`, it works.

Comment: It's relevant where in the function definition you place the attribute string. Where is it in yours? I have one that works like so: `void __attribute__ ((constructor)) constructor() { ... }`. Note that it's after `void` and before `constructor()`.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's worth noting that shared library constructors are generally *Considered Harmful* due to their ability to mess up the initial state of the program before `main` is entered. The most infamous example is OpenAL, which (at least at one time; I believe it was since fixed but I'm not sure) munged with ALSA library/device state in a way that prevented the application from later opening the ALSA device itself. Proper libraries should try their best to avoid having any global state, and if absolutely necessary, should use lazy initialization on the first library call, not ctors.

Comment: @Dan Fego, I tried different placements including the one you suggested above. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @R.. I understand the risks involved. But I am just going to initialize some variables specific to my library.

Comment: @Santhosh Can you please post a minimal [example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem, and preferably your compilation lines and output and the way you're calling it?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a function named _init or _fini in the library already? If so, these will conflict with the startup code and prevent running your constructors...

Comment: @Dan, Please see the sample code in my question.. its very basic. Have also given the commands I used.. may be I am missing something in the way .so should be built ?

Comment: @Santhosh I'm not 100% sure why this is, but on a similarly old box (but not on a new one), I can reproduce your problem. If I change your `gcc` and `ld` steps to a single `gcc` step, however, it seems to go away. Care to try that out and report back? Mine was: `gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libsmlib.so smlib.c`.

Comment: @Dan you are right..If I build the so in one step then it works. The typical version numbering of the .so files is pretty confusing to me. Is it really required to have those .so.1 and .so.1.0 files ? Probably its required when you want to release it a bigger project and to incremental updates ? You said you see the problem in a old box, what is old on that, kernel version or gcc or something else ? And Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @Santhosh See my answer below for an explanation on why this is happening. As for the `.so.1` stuff, I don't think it's necessary -- just convention.

Comment: Also see the discussion of constructors, `-Ur` and `-r` in the [`ld` man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld). `-init=name` may be useful, too because it sets `DT_INIT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I've taken a look at this, and it looks like what's happening is that your intermediate `gcc` step (using `-c`) is causing the issue. Here's my interpretation of what I'm seeing.

When you compile as a `.o` with `setup()`, `gcc` just treats it as a normal function (since you're not compiling as a `.so`, so it doesn't care). Then, `ld` doesn't see any `_init()` or anything like a `DT_INIT` in the ELF's dynamic section, and assumes there's no constructors.

When you compile as a `.o` with `_init()`, `gcc` also treats it as a normal function. In fact, it looks to me like **the object files are identical** except for the names of the functions themselves! So once again, `ld` looks at the `.o` file, but this time sees a `_init()` function, which it knows it's looking for, and decides it's a constructor, and correspondingly creates a `DT_INIT` entry in the new `.so`.

Finally, if you do the compilation and linking in one step, like this:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libsmlib.so smlib.c
```

Then what happens is that `gcc` sees and understands the `__attribute__ ((constructor))` in the context of creating a shared object, and creates a `DT_INIT` entry accordingly.

Short version: use `gcc` to compile and link in one step. You can use `-Wl` (see the man page) for passing in extra options like `-soname` if required, like `-Wl,-soname,libsmlib.so.1`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in one step. What makes it work is using gcc with -shared to link, not ld.

Comment: Is there no option to have constructor but with 2 steps (.o then .so)? It is necessary for CMake projects

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html) :

"Shared libraries must not be compiled with the gcc arguments -nostartfiles'' or-nostdlib''. If those arguments are used, the constructor/destructor routines will not be executed (unless special measures are taken)."

gcc/ld doesn't set the DT_INIT bit in the elf header when -nostdlib is used . You can check objdump -p and look for the section INIT in both cases. In **attribute** ((constructor)) case you wont find that INIT section . But for __init case you will find INIT section in the shared library.